# Unit test for save method failing with error pointing at fc.showSaveDialog(null)

Tags: java, unit-testing, filechooser

As per the title I have

> fc.showSaveDialog(null)

and my unit test for the save method is failing and pointing at the line with that statement.

I realize it is likely failing because I have it set to null rather than a stage but I would also like to understand why it cannot be null if that is the case.

```java
public static void save(String text) throws IOException {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

        //Start file chooser in project directory
        String currentPath = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File(currentPath));

        // Define extension filters
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter txtFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter pdfFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF Files (*.pdf)", "*.pdf");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(txtFilter, pdfFilter);


//////////////////////////////THIS LINE
        File file = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
///////////////////////////////////////



        if (file != null) {
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter selectedFilter = fc.getSelectedExtensionFilter();

            if (selectedFilter == txtFilter) {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                writer.write(text);
                writer.close();
            } else if (selectedFilter == pdfFilter) {
                savePdf(text, file);
            }
        }   
    }
```

This is my unit test. The key press simulation is meant to just enter A when the file chooser pops up but my test does not make it that far before failing.

```java
    @Test
    void testSave() throws IOException {

        String text = "hello world";
        FileFunctions.save(text);

        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            // Simulate a key press
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

I can add the entire failure trace if necessary but the main part is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the
>   event thread only; currentThread = main   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.CommonDialogs$ExtensionFilter.(CommonDialogs.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.convertExtensionFilters(QuantumToolkit.java:1614)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.showFileChooser(QuantumToolkit.java:1557)
>     at javafx.stage.FileChooser.showDialog(FileChooser.java:416)    at
>   javafx.stage.FileChooser.showSaveDialog(FileChooser.java:392)     at
>   assignment1.FileFunctions.save(FileFunctions.java:87)     at
>   assignment1.unitTests.testSave(unitTests.java:18)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

In the source for FileChooser.java, it seems like a null argument for that method is handled:

```java
private List<File> showDialog(final Window ownerWindow,
                                  final FileChooserType fileChooserType) {
        FileChooserResult result = Toolkit.getToolkit().showFileChooser(
                (ownerWindow != null) ? ownerWindow.getPeer() : null,
    .......................................................................
```

So I think the issue lies elsewhere.

Source: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/stage/FileChooser.java#L411